# Is this possible to get session for smarty application assigned in Yii application on same server

Tags: php, yii2, smarty, session-variables

I am searching this for 2 days but still did not find answer. i know its possible to share session across multiple yii application. But here in my case. i Have 2 web apps. One is smarty and other is yii application. Now i want to set session in yii controller and want to get that session in my smarty webapp. Is this possible? IF no then what is the best and secure method to pass values from one web app to another on a same server.

My web apps directory structure is

```
http://localhost/yii/index.php
http://localhost/smarty/index.php
```

Answer (score 0):

You may store sessions in your database - just put db session settings in your config file and create proper database table. It's described [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-sessions-cookies.html) But you will have to change session table and use your own CustomDbSession class.

```
return [
    'components' => [
        'session' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\DbSession',
            // 'db' => 'mydb',  // the application component ID of the DB connection. Defaults to 'db'.
            // 'sessionTable' => 'my_session', // session table name. Defaults to 'session'.
        ],
    ],
];
```

Add 'user_id' integer field to session table schema.

```
CREATE TABLE session
(
    id CHAR(40) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    expire INTEGER,
    data BLOB,
    user_id INTEGER
)
```

[More Detail](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-sessions-cookies.html)

Comment: Thank you @shahzad. I had followed the same but here problem with this method i will need to fetch the data from database and what i wanted is user login on both web apps with yii app login form..
I am setting session for smarty app in yii login controller and redirecting to dashboard. Now i want that if user go to smarty web app dashboard then he should have already logged in.